# Force to show level picker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-indoor-maps

Is it possible to show and configure the floor picker of google map even I'm not zooming on an indoor place?

I want to show and use the level picker for other reasons (indoor maps not related to google)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you can disable default floor picker via [`setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(false)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings#setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(boolean)) and add a custom floor picker layout over `MapFragment` (or `MapView`) and show/hide it whenever you want. Also in that case it is easier to organize the processing of its events.

Comment: yes I know, I just wanted to use the component of google maps that's it

Comment: @AmineHarbaoui Seems, its possible, especially just show it, but it can be too complex to add custom behavior for it, exactly for "use the level picker for other reasons".

Comment: I think there's no way to show it manually, it's always related to the indoor maps of google